# 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

The 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://stackoverflow.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Phew! Finally an election. All the best for all candidates!

Comment: Come on, @nicael!  My trollvote grows restless!

Comment: Good luck to all candidates!

Comment: You can all breathe easy:  I'm officially not running again this year ;)

Comment: Martjin Pieters i running this year! http://stackoverflow.com/election/6#post-29479702

Comment: Wow... so many really good people are running. I don't know who'll I'll end up voting for, since there are so many people who I feel would be good moderators.

Comment: @lyndact:  **Do not make edits as minor as this.** This not only serves no value, but you've also managed to bump an old and no longer relevant topic.

Comment: @Makoto Some people just never stop being excited about elections, yes? ;)

Comment: @Makoto it looks like it served up two badges: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4972189/lyndact?tab=badges  I think that may have been the motive...

Answer (score 20):

Is there a (trivially easy) way to see what my moderator score would be if I were to be nominated?  Just curious.

Comment: You could calculate it using the requirements here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247138/164200

Comment: Is there any SEDE query that can calculate this?

Comment: @Roombatron5000 I wrote one: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/297666/moderator-candidate-score

Comment: @tbodt I think you must be counting badges more than once otherwise I'm not sure how I scored 42.  It is, on the other hand, a very gratifying number. :)

Comment: @tvanfosson It's supposed to multiply six by nine. I'll debug it.

Comment: @tvanfosson OK, fixed it. (btw, why does Jeff Atwood only get 36?)

Comment: was about to (no laugh at me) flag the answer for beeing a question, but the op is not a question either before i figured out this was community wiki .. this election process and algorythm is nice. Wish it would be that neet in real life. Wish politics was that easy. Thanks.